# Nextjs fetching data from child component

Tags: next.js, cors, fetch

I have page.tsx component where I need to get the current pathname, so it's a **client component**. Then I have a **child server component** where I would like to fetch data based on the pathname passed as prop. However, when I try to fetch the data I get these errors:

> Uncaught (in promise) Error: Failed to fetch data. at fetchRadio

> Access to fetch at 'https://api.example.com' from origin
> 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No
> 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
> resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's
> mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

The parent component:

```
"use client";

import * as React from "react";
import Radio from "@/components/ui/radio/radio";
import { usePathname } from "next/navigation";

export default function Page() {
    const pathName = usePathname();

    return <Radio pathName={pathName} />;
}
```

Child server component:

```
import * as React from "react";
import { fetchRadio } from "@/lib/data";

export default async function Radio({ pathName }: { pathName: string }) {
    const radio = await fetchRadio(pathName);

    return (
        {/* ... */}
    );
}
```

Fetch function:

```
export async function fetchRadio(pathName: string){
    try {
        const radios = await fetch("https://api.example.com");
        const data = await radios.json();

        console.log(pathName); // for now I just want to log the pathname
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error:", error);
        throw new Error("Failed to fetch data.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmm this is not really a NextJS issue, but a [CORS issue](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS). Client side request get's blocked directly by the browser since https://api.example.com does not allow cross-origin requests. Your localhost being not the same origin as example.com.

One way to fix it, usually 3rd party API's have a CORS management section where you can whitelist your localhost or your domain name for specific requests.

Comment: But in another component, I am making request on the same api with no issue. And when I change the main component to server component and test it without the pathname, it works.

Comment: Correct, in a server component you don't have the browser blocking this request. Client Side components will make the API call from the client.

Comment: Oh I see now. Thanks mate, I'll ty to figure it out now.